# Find f(x) if $\int_{1}^{x}f(s)ds=\left ( f(x) \right )^{2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let be $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function
> such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for $x>1$. We know that for every $x \geq 1$
> it satisfies that: \begin{align*} \int_{1}^{x}f(s)ds=\left ( f(x)
>  \right )^{2} \end{align*} Find $f=f(x)$

What I know by the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is that:

\begin{align*}
F(x)= \left ( f(x) \right )^{2}=\int_{1}^{x}f(s)ds \Longrightarrow  \frac{dF(x)}{dx}=2f(x)
\end{align*}

I'm stuck at this point, what am I doing wrong or how can I continue to find $f$?

Comment: I saw this exact question only a day or two ago on this site but I can't find it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Differentate the equality w.r.t. $x$ : if gives you
$$f(x)=2f'(x)f(x)$$

With the hypothesis that $f(x)\neq0$ for all $x > 1$, you should be able to conclude.

Comment: So, $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ right?

Comment: On $[1,+\infty)$, you must have $f'(x)=1/2$ indeed, but be careful, you have also $f(1)=0$. This gives you $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{2}$ on $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Nevermind, the question gives that $f$ is differentiable. I misread. My apologies! Ignore me @luisegf